# Visual studio, diagnostic tools. Does hot reload keeping instances of closed windows?

Tags: visual-studio

I am using the diagnostic tools to see if some instances are collected by the garbage collector.

In my case, I have a main window and and button that open another windows with ShowDialog() method.

I take two snapshots, one when the second is opened and the second one when I have closed the window.

In the second snapshop, if I check the heap, in the managed memory window, I see that the instance of the window is still listed.

Is it true that if I mark the check to show the dead objects, the windows is listed too, so it seems the window is a dead obejct, but I am not sure what does it means. Is the windows recollected by the garbage collector? Is it still in memory pending to be recollected?

Another message  that I get is this: XAML hot reload types are present in the managed heap. This may cause objects to be retained that would be otherwise garbage collected. Does it means that becuse of hot reloaded this windows is not collected?

Thanks.